# Difference between GIT and GITHub in android studio new project checkout?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

What is difference between the below two options while checking out new project

1, File - > new -> Project from Version control -> GitHub

2, File - > new -> Project from Version control -> Git

My understanding is, Using first option we can checkout a repository from GitHub. Then what is the use of second option?

Answer (score 1):

**Git** is a revision control system, a tool to manage your source code history.

**GitHub** is a hosting service for Git repositories.

So they are not the same thing: Git is the tool, GitHub is the service for projects that use Git.
[Git vs Github](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-git-and-github/)

Comment: But i can able to checkout GITLab projects using second option, why?                       Is second option common to GITHub and GitLab?

Comment: @Raj I would suppose so. I have not tried it, but both run on `git` and should thus feature the second option.

Comment: @lucidbrot Yes, both are working in GIT. But I dont know why the first option is needed then. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Raj I don't know, but perhaps option 1 offers some additional functionality like forking a stranger's github repo